# ViewPager doesnt show images in more than 1 Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-nested-fragment

My app is a news app, with news listing fragment, `NewsDetailsFragment` (which contains menu, search, etc). I am using the single activity model and each screen is represented by a Fragment. `NewsDetailsFragment` includes a `ViewPager` (gallery).

When I navigate to `NewsDetailsFragment` initially, the gallery is loaded, now if I load a new instance of `NewsDetailsFragment` fragment, to choose another news from the menu, doing a search, etc. The `ViewPager` in the 2nd `NewsDetailsFragment` won't display the images, although the `Log` shows that everything works fine, data is there, adapter calls getView()...

So basically if there is 1 loaded gallery ViewPager, any more `NewsDetailsFragment` won't show their galleries, only if I press Back till I have no fragment (hence no ViewPager running), only then if I open a new instance of `NewsDetailsFragment` it will load the gallery.

I hope I explained clearly. I tried my best and I'm clueless now.

This is how I pass the gallery data to the ViewPager after it is loaded (code excerpt from NewsDetailsFragment):

```
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) getView().findViewById(R.id.vpAlbum);
ArticleAlbumAdapter adapter = new ArticleAlbumAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), article.album);
pager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

ArticleAlbumAdapter:

```
public class ArticleAlbumAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
private List<String> urlList;

public ArticleAlbumAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<String> urlList)
{
    super(fm);
    this.urlList = urlList;

    Log.d("ArticleAlbumAdapter()", "urlList=" + urlList);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position)
{
    Log.d("ArticleAlbumAdapter.getItem()", "position=" + position + ", url=" + urlList.get(position));

    Fragment image = new AlbumImageFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("url", urlList.get(position));
    bundle.putInt("pos", position);
    image.setArguments(bundle);

    return  image;
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return urlList.size();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the ViewPager your current Fragment's getChildFragmentManager() rather than the FragmentManager of the activity.  Based on your description, I'm assuming your main screen which creates the first ViewPager is also a Fragment.  Since the ViewPager is a child to your Fragment and it in turn is creating child Fragments, it needs the child FragmentManager rather than the main one.

Comment: can u give me a code snippet? do u mean pass this to the adapter? Also I dont see getChildFragmentManager() in the android.support.v4.app.Fragment API

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: thanks, this fixed it. I was using an old version of the support lib that doesnt have getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: Excellent...glad you were able to get it going!